# Subplot in Python for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I received back a dictionary from a SQL search, then I want to iterate over the dictionary to crop an image on the x, y, h, w. I want to then display the original image, an edited image. This I have accomplished. What I cannot figure out is how to display the results in a figure using matplotlib.pyplot. Here is my code:

```
sql_result = get_rois(config, "145", "a")

img_dir = '../imgs/'

make palaeographical chart
fig = plt.figure()

#Iterate over the list
for num, result in enumerate(aleph_rois):
    #make path to image
    img_path = os.path.join(imgs, sql_result['file_name'])

    #declare variables for cropping character
    x = sql_result['x']
    y = sql_result['y']
    w = sql_result['w']
    h = sql_result['h']

    #crop to character
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    th0 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(crop, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 2)

    #OTSU Binarization to fill
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop,(5,5),0)
    ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    frg_loc = str(sql_result['artefact_siglum']) + " " + str(result['line_id']) + " roi:" + str(sql_result['roi_id'])

    #create fig
    plt.title(frg_loc)
    plt.imshow(th1, cmap='Greys_r')
```

The above is obviously failing. I've tried several options, and I think I am having the problem where the images are overwriting each other in the figure. But the objective is to have th0 and th1 in a 2 column figure, with the rows defined by the number of results in sql_results. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understood correct - however, as a start of discussion at least:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 3
fig, axs = plt.subplots(N, 2)
for row in range(N):
    axs[row, 0].imshow(th0)
    axs[row, 1].imshow(th1, cmap = 'Reds_r')
```

results in

[image]

(image content is just exemplary and not part of the code of this SO answer<sup>TM</sup>)

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. I was confusing the Matrix logic.